# LED strip cable and connector sizing

Tags: power, cables, ws2812b

I'm trying to power a [LED strip](https://www.tinytronics.nl/shop/nl/verlichting/led-strips/led-strips/ws2812b-digitale-5050-rgb-led-strip-60-leds-1m). It contains 140 WS2812B with 60 LEDs/m so it is around 2.3 m. According to the datasheet, the LEDs has a 60 mA current consumption. Based on the pure math its 140*60 = 8.4 A.
My problem is cable and power connector capacity.
According to this [link](https://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm) I would need to use an AWG 12 cable.

I want to power it up at least from the two ends. The question is noob from here. Does this means that each cable is enough to be able to carry 4.2 A? As this would mean it is enough to use an AWG15 cable. If I going further for example if I power it up 2 additional point in the middle of the LED strip does this means the power cable from the PSU to the LED strip has to be able to carry 2.1 A (AWG 18 cable). Furthermore as this is a custom stuff, I'm planning to use a JST connector. The one I have is able to handle 3 A according to its datasheet. So If I'm powering the strip at 4 points, AWG 18 cables and a JST connector is sufficient?
Or am I totally wrong?

[image]

Comment: I couldn't see any current consumption data in the datasheets I found. Could you please put a link to the datasheet you refer, and a snippet showing the consumption data?

Comment: You are right. Just wire all cables from the 5V PSU ...

Comment: The *power transmission* column used a lot of assumptions. Instead, you should calculate the acceptable voltage drop. The strips are fairly forgiving, unfortunately the spec usually won't tell you the minimum voltage required to keep the constant current circuits working. I have found it to be about 4.2 V. If you are only building one, measure it yourself. Set all LEDs to full brightness and lower the voltage until the LEDs start to dim.

Comment: The same link has a nice calculator tool. Chose 6vdc and plug in your numbers and you will get the estimated voltage drop. Change the wire gauge to get an idea of what cable you should use. The key factor will be the distance your runs will be. Longer runs means higher resistance, and at high current, means higher voltage droop.

Comment: Thanks @Antonio51

Comment: Unless your wiring is long and all packed together, you can use the less conservative "chassis wiring" numbers.  The other comments are correct, though, better to focus first on the expected IR loss.  As an estimate, if you use 16 AWG, wire you would have a round trip IR drop of about 0.5V over 2.3m.  (at 8.4A)  This sounds very reasonable to me.

Comment: Regarding the connector.  It is OK to use a 3A connector pin for 2.1A.  Remember, that each power pin will have a return (GND) that carries the same current.  This is especially important when calculating IR loss of the wires.

Comment: note that the typical current is FAR less than the max; you'll only see that voltage drop at full-blast solid white. Many LED pixel driver libs contain functions to limit the max current, which can also help if your wires are under-sized. I try to plan for 33% of max, and if it goes over for a second or two no big whoop...